# crear arraylist dinamicos dentro de un bucle Java

Tags: java, array, bucle-for, arraylist, bucles

tengo un problema hay alguna manera de crear arraylist de manera dinámica dentro de un bucle for.
filecolum.size siempre va a cambiar de valor puede ser 1, 5,7,etc, y dependiendo del valor se deben crear esa cantidad de arraylist.

```
for (int u = 0; u < filecolumn.size(); u++) {
ArrayList<Integer> numeric1(u) = new ArrayList<Integer>();
}
```

Alguien tiene una idea u otra opción que pueda implementar para realizar esta tarea.
Muchas Gracias

Comment: Creo que debieses ser más claro en tu pregunta, por otro lado, creo que te refieres a crear "ArrayLists contenidos dentro de un ArrayList", podrías hacer un `ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>` y dentro de ese ArrayList colocar la cantidad que quieres

Comment: porque no usas una lista y asi te olvidas del tamanno, a las listas no hay q especificarles ningun tamanno List<int>list = new List<int>();

Comment: @Japv `ArrayList` es una lista.

Comment: @E.Betanzos, pensé que era c#

Comment: @Japv en C# también es una lista.

Comment: @E.Betanzos, son listas pero con concepciones diferentes, el arraylist permite cualquier tipo de datos en cualquier posición, mientras que el list admite el tipo de datos que le especifique, el arraylist se inventó primero, el list vino después con los tipos de datos genericos

Comment: @Japv es así como comentas, pero más allá de los detalles de implementación particulares, ambas ofrecen la ventaja del tamaño dinámico. Por lo que cambiar el uso de una por otra solo por este motivo realmente no aporta nada.

Comment: Una opción sería fuera del bucle hacer un array normal y ponerle el fileColum.size
Y dentro del for al array contenedor por cada posición i (ve interando) hacerle un ArrayList si mañana tengo tiempo igual te intento hacer código mientras puedes probar lo que te he dicho